# Martin-Löf randomness characterization

Tags: randomness, kolmogorov-complexity

In his 1973 paper [On the notion of a random sequence](http://www.cs.bu.edu/fac/lnd/dvi/ran72.pdf), Levin states (without proving) a characterization of Martin-Löf randomness by writing

> **Theorem 3.** A sequence $\alpha$ is random w.r.t. the distribution $P$ in the Martin-Löf sense if and only if the probability ratio $P(\alpha_n)/ R(\alpha_n)$ is bounded below

where $R$ is the universal semicomputable (semi)measure.

I feel a bit confused how this ratio could not be bounded below, being the ratio of two positive quantities it should always be bounded below by $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio should be bounded below by a positive constant. Equivalently, its infimum should be positive.

Comment: I wonder whether I should have been able to understand this by reading the text...can you point me to some proof of this statement?

Comment: I suggest checking textbooks on the area.